# How to create a leptokurtic/platykurtic distribution in scipy having four moments?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, normal-distribution

As [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) says, we can easily calculate the first four moments of a normal distribution by this:

```
mean, var, skew, kurt = norm.stats(moments='mvsk')
```

But I can't find it on their documentation, that by having all four moments `mean, var, skew, kurt`(skewness and kurtosis) how can you create a semi-normal distribution object? (for example, how can I make a leptokurtic or a platykurtic distribution in scipy?)

P.S. I know I can use [scipy.stats.skewnorm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html) for skewed normal. But that doesn't accept the 4th-moment kurtosis either.

Comment: Well, a normal distribution is uniquely determined by its mean and variance -- all other moments are functions of those. So mean and variance is all you need.

Comment: @RobertDodier But a semi-normal distribution can be skewed and have kurtosis other than 3. For a perfect normal distribution, skewness is always 0 and kurtosis is 3.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, sorry, I overlooked the bit about semi-normal distributions. If you can use another system, maybe R has the semi-normal distribution. If you must use Scipy, you might have to implement it yourself, although maybe before doing that, ask about it in a Scipy developers forum to see if anyone has already worked on it.

Comment: Do you mean half normal?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux No, I mean a semi-normal with a kurtosis other than 3, as you can see in this picture: https://cdn.analystprep.com/cfa-level-1-exam/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/05085139/page-64.png

Comment: Are you referring to the semi-normal distribution as shown in https://p-distribution.com/chi-squared-distribution/#seminormal?  That distribution doesn't seem to have enough parameters to be able to specify the mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis independently.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser To be exact, I needed "leptokurtic distribution".

Comment: If you don't need the semi-normal distribution specifically, you should probably remove that name from the question.  There are many distributions in SciPy that are leptokurtic (e.g. `scipy.stats.laplace`, `scipy.stats.skewnorm`), but there is no function that accepts the mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis as inputs and returns a distribution with those moments.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thank you. I think ` scipy.stats.laplace_asymmetric` is closer to what I want.

Comment: This post is relevant https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/483215/102879

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function that given with 4 moments returns a distribution. But a close alternative is the Asymmetric Laplace distribution in [scipy.stats.laplace_asymmetric](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.laplace_asymmetric.html) which is a skewed leptokurtic.

I don't have an answer for platykurtic distribution for now. If I had I'll edit the answer.